# How do I can call each other function in the different view in MFC?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc, imagemagick

I have make a view in dialog in MFC.
and I want to call a function from dialog to view.
How can I call each other function in the different view?

Here is code Also I have attached as [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-5zI4MO34u_eDMydVRxMEJia3M/view?usp=sharing)

```
void Cmfc_test5Dlg::OnDropFiles(HDROP hDropInfo)
{
int nFiles;
char szPathName[MAX_PATH]; 
CString strFileName;
nFiles = ::DragQueryFile( hDropInfo, 0xFFFFFFFF, szPathName, MAX_PATH );

{
::DragQueryFile(hDropInfo, 0, szPathName, MAX_PATH);
}
::DragFinish(hDropInfo);
CDialog::OnDropFiles(hDropInfo);

DoDisplayImage(); <---Here is My call function.

CDialogEx::OnDropFiles(hDropInfo);

}
```

and Here is another function

```
void CTestview::DoDisplayImage()
{
  CDC *pDC = GetDC();
  if (pDC != NULL && m_Image.isValid() ) 
    {
      CRect rectClient;
      GetClientRect(rectClient);
      pDC->FillSolidRect(rectClient,pDC->GetBkColor());
      // Set up the Windows bitmap header
      BITMAPINFOHEADER bmi;
      bmi.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);    // Size of structure
      bmi.biWidth = m_Image.columns();          // Bitmaps width in pixels
      bmi.biHeight = (-1)*m_Image.rows();       // Bitmaps height n pixels
      bmi.biPlanes = 1;                         // Number of planes in the image
       bmi.biBitCount = 32;                      // The number of bits per pixel
       bmi.biCompression = BI_RGB;               // The type of 
       ...
```

and the DoDisplayImage function called from here

```
void CTestview::OnDraw(CDC* pDC)
{
    CDocument* pDoc = GetDocument();
    // TODO: add draw code here
    DoDisplayImage();
}
```

But, as you know, My problem is that I can't call the DoDisplayImage() in void Cmfc_test5Dlg::OnDropFiles(HDROP hDropInfo) function also I want to get szPathName of OnDropFiles function in DoDisplayImage.

What should I do for solving for this problems?

## update 1

There are error when I make as following.

1>d:\work\mfc_test5\mfc_test5\Testview.h(29): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>d:\work\mfc_test5\mfc_test5\Testview.h(29): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>d:\work\mfc_test5\mfc_test5\Testview.h(29): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>
1>Build FAILED.

In TestView.h,

```
#pragma once



// CTestview view

class CTestview : public CScrollView
{
    DECLARE_DYNCREATE(CTestview)

protected:
    CTestview();           // protected constructor used by dynamic creation
    virtual ~CTestview();

public:
#ifdef _DEBUG
    virtual void AssertValid() const;
#ifndef _WIN32_WCE
    virtual void Dump(CDumpContext& dc) const;
#endif
#endif

protected:
    virtual void OnDraw(CDC* pDC);      // overridden to draw this view
    virtual void OnInitialUpdate();     // first time after construct

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
public:
    CTestView* pTestView; <---- is this right?
};
```

Here is code Also I have attached as [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-5zI4MO34u_eDMydVRxMEJia3M/view?usp=sharing)

## update2

I have done as following.

```
// mfc_test5Dlg.h : header file
//

#pragma once
#include "afxcmn.h"


// Cmfc_test5Dlg dialog
class CTestview;//adding
class Cmfc_test5Dlg : public CDialogEx
{
// Construction
public:
    Cmfc_test5Dlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL);    // standard constructor
    CTestview* pTestView;//adding

// Dialog Data
    enum { IDD = IDD_MFC_TEST5_DIALOG };

    protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support


Cmfc_test5Dlg::Cmfc_test5Dlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialogEx(Cmfc_test5Dlg::IDD, pParent)
    , m_CString(_T(""))
{
    m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);
    pTestView = NULL; //adding
}
```

But I can't understand at this part how to implement it in my case.

```
You have to set pTestView each time the dialog is created. For example:

void CTestview::foo()
{
    Cmfc_test5Dlg dlg(...);
    dlg.pTestView = this;
    dlg.DoModal();
}
```

Comment: Why is it that you *can't call the DoDisplayImage()*? Is that because you dont have any reference to the view?

Comment: In your second edit you put `CTestView` versus `CTestview` that's causing the error (I meant to write `CTestview` in the answer). I said put a `CTestview` pointer in the dialog, not in `CTestview`

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Would you please help me in my code with link

Comment: I updated the answer. You should try it on a simple c++ console program first.

Answer (score 2):

In MFC's Document/View architecture you do NOT call View's method from outside.

The way to get the View to draw something is through its Document by updating the content and invoking UpdateAllViews(), possibly with hint (for optimization).

Answer (score 0):

This is basic c++. You have class A and B which are not related. How do you access A from B? Try this console program:

```
class TA {
public:
    void foo() {
        cout << "TA\n";
    }
};

class TB {
public:
    TA *A;
    TB() {
        A = nullptr;
    }

    void foo() {
        if (A)
            A->foo();
    }
};

int main()
{
    TA *a = new TA;
    TB *b = new TB;

    b->A = a;
    b->foo(); //prints "TA"

    delete a;
    delete b;
    return 0;
}
```

It's the same in MFC. You can declare a pointer to `CTestView` and use that pointer in the dialog class:

```
class CTestview;
class Cmfc_test5Dlg : public CDialogEx
{
public:
    CTestView* pTestView;
    ...
};

include "TestView.h"
Cmfc_test5Dlg::Cmfc_test5Dlg()
{
    pTestView = NULL;
}
```

You have to set `pTestView` each time the dialog is created. For example:

```
void CTestview::foo()
{
    Cmfc_test5Dlg dlg(...);
    dlg.pTestView = this;
    dlg.DoModal();
}
```

Then use `pTestView->DoDisplayImage()` anywhere in `Cmfc_test5Dlg`. For example:

```
void Cmfc_test5Dlg::OnDropFiles(HDROP hDropInfo)
{
   ...
   if (pTestView != NULL)
       pTestView->DoDisplayImage();
}
```

Another way is to use global variables:

```
CTestview *global_TestView;
CTestview::CTestview()
{
    global_TestView = this;
    ...
}

//---- another cpp file:
extern CTestview *global_TestView;
...
void Cmfc_test5Dlg::OnDropFiles(HDROP hDropInfo)
{
   ...
   if (global_TestView != NULL)
       global_TestView->DoDisplayImage();
}
```

But this method can fail for a number of reason. For example if there could be more than one `CTestview`.

ps, don't call `CDialogEx::OnDropFiles(hDropInfo);` and `CDialogEx::OnDropFiles(hDropInfo);` consecutively, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks But I can't understand exactly here "This is basic c++, it's not MFC specific. You can declare a pointer to CTestView and use that pointer in the dialog class:

class CTestview;
class Cmfc_test5Dlg : public CDialogEx
{
public:
    CTestView* pTestView;
    ...
};

include "TestView.h"
Cmfc_test5Dlg::Cmfc_test5Dlg()
{
    pTestView = NULL;
}"   Would you please let me know once more ?

Comment: I have update as link. would you please check my code?

Comment: I mean it is basic c++, that means you don't know basic c++. It is very difficult to find your way in MFC without knowing basic c++.

Comment: Thanks but this case is working between different class. BTW, is this works between different view like in my case( dialog class and view class)?

Comment: Read the explanation again. I also showed a different method using "global variables". Do a google search for "c++ global variables". There are a million examples.

Comment: But you told me that don't use global variable method.(But this method can fail for a number of reason)

Comment: Global variables should give you a better idea of what is going on. You are in one class, you are trying to access a function in a different class. `CTestview` is a c++ class. `Cmfc_test5Dlg` is a c++ class. Read up on "c++ scope" and global variables. Once you understand it then you can use different methods instead of global variables.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to display an image in the view whenever a file is dropped on a child dialog?

Supply a pointer to the view as additional parameter in the constructor of the dialog and store it in the dialogs member variable `m_view`. Then call it:

```
m_view->DoDisplayImage();
```